# Zend Framework POST data is not displayed or processed

Tags: php, zend-framework

This is my form: Profile form

It has two elements password and passwordConf

```
    $this->password= new Zend_Form_Element_Password("password",array("label"=>"Password","required"=>true));
    $this->passwordConf= new Zend_Form_Element_Password("confpassword",array("label"=>"Retype","required"=>true));
    $this->passwordConf->addValidator("Identical",array("token"=>"password"));
    $this->save=new Zend_Form_Element_Submit("save",array("label"=>"Change Password","class"=>"btn btn-primary"));
```

So I have an instance of this in controller and pass it POST data

```
    $profileForm= new Application_Form_Profile();

    if($_POST)
    if($profileForm->isValid($_POST))
    {

        $membersTable= new Application_Model_DbTable_Members();
        $member=$membersTable->find($this->user->id)->current();
        $member->password=sha1($profileForm->getValue("password").$member->salt);
        $this->_helper->flashMessenger(array("type"=>"success","content"=>"Password Changed!"));
        $this->_redirect("");

        $member->save();
    }

    $this->view->profileForm=$profileForm;
}
```

but for some reason, I get the Zend Empty Error message. I've also noticed that the Form fields are not populated.
I checked the response in Chrome and it appears post data is passed to the page just fine. Even did a print_r(POST) and even that looks fine and dandy with all the data. I did that before and after the block of code above, but doesn't work. It just does not populate the form despite the data being passed.

PS: The error message is only for password confirm field. The password field works fine

Comment: `Zend_Form_Element_Password` is set by default to not to re-show the value which is a security related thing.

Comment: that's okay, but the validation fails on password conf even though i type in data

Comment: wow figured this out. Apparently, the name of the variable $this->passwordConf and name of the field must match

Comment: You should really be using `addElement()` in your form classes, eg `$this->addElement(new Zend_Form_Element_...)`

Comment: I've grown used to this syntax.Its faster, and let's you access form elements directly using $form->elementname isntead of $form->getElement("name")

Comment: When using `addElement()`, you can still use `$form->elementName`. It's also no faster as `Zend_Form::__set()` just calls `addElement` internally anyway

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here was that the nae of the class variable and the name of the element must match

```
$this->passwordConf= new Zend_Form_Element_Password("confpassword",array("label"=>"Retype","required"=>true));
```

i.e `$this->passwordConf` and `confpassword` should not be different otherwise this error will happen